# NuxtJS with custom Pinia store module - error on generating static files

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, pinia

I made a simple test Pinia store, published it to my company private Gitlab package registry and imported into a NuxtJS frontend, all of this with no problems.

(The package is transpiled with babel, so `index.js` require and exports `dist/index.js`, not sure if this helps)

The errors arises when running `npm run generate` to generate static files.

##### The Pinia store

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useMyStore = defineStore({
    id: 'myStore',
    state: () => {
        return {
            // properties
        };
    },
    actions: {
        myMethod() {
            // do something
        },
    },
});
```

##### The store `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@my-compaty/my-store",
  "version": "0.1.13",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "test": "vitest --run --config ./vitest.config.js --coverage"
  },
  "author": "My Company",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.29.8",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
    "jsdom": "^21.1.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.33",
    "vitest": "^0.29.8"
  }
}
```

##### The Nuxt page `script` section

```js
<script>
import { useMyStore } from "@my-company/my-store";

export default {
    name: "TestPage",
    data() {
        return {
            store: useMyStore(),
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

##### The errors

```
node@3fd5719bc9c1:~/app$ npm run generate

> my-project@1.0.0 generate
> nuxt generate

ℹ Production build                                                                                                                  10:45:51
ℹ Bundling only for client side                                                                                                     10:45:51
ℹ Target: static                                                                                                                    10:45:51
ℹ Using components loader to optimize imports                                                                                       10:45:51
ℹ Discovered Components: node_modules/.cache/nuxt/components/readme.md                                                              10:45:51
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                               10:45:51
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                                                              10:45:51

✖ Client
  Compiled with some errors in 3.97s


Hash: 262c263c053297fbcd65
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 3972ms
Built at: 04/03/2023 10:45:56 AM
     Asset       Size  Chunks               Chunk Names
114efd3.js  119 bytes       0  [immutable]  app
1ed1302.js    210 KiB       1  [immutable]  commons/app
3ce07f3.js   7.83 KiB       7  [immutable]  vendors/pages/index
66af92b.js   1.86 KiB       2  [immutable]  components/nuxt-logo
7202d98.js  508 bytes       4  [immutable]  pages/index
  LICENSES  421 bytes                       
b2aeacf.js   53.2 KiB       6  [immutable]  vendors/app
fb5a20b.js   6.59 KiB       3  [immutable]  components/tutorial
fedd8ab.js   2.33 KiB       5  [immutable]  runtime
Entrypoint app = fedd8ab.js 1ed1302.js b2aeacf.js 114efd3.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 1206:44-52
Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./node_modules/@my-company/my-store/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/router.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 953:18-29
Can't import the named export 'effectScope' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./node_modules/@my-company/my-store/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/router.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 1434:16-27
Can't import the named export 'effectScope' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./node_modules/@my-company/my-store/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/router.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 24:30-48
Can't import the named export 'getCurrentInstance' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./node_modules/@my-company/my-store/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/router.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/client.js

...

 FATAL  Nuxt build error                                                                                                            10:45:56

  at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:1861:21)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async WebpackBundler.build (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:1826:5)
  at async Builder.build (node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js:249:5)
  at async ensureBuild (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-generate.js:117:3)
  at async Object.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-generate.js:234:7)
  at async NuxtCommand.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:356:7)
```

The errors are actually way more that these, but all in the form of

```
Can't import the named export 'xxxx' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after messing with the code the error output changed a bit and tells something about `Nuxt Bridge`, so searched online about it and found the Nuxt [Migrate to Bridge](https://nuxt.com/docs/bridge/overview) guide: long story short, basically I had to upgrade from nuxt `2.15` to `2.16` and update `generate` script.

Following the guide solved my problem.